# Servicemix ActiveMQ Web Console & LDAP not

Tags: apache-servicemix

I'm using ServiceMix 7.0 with ActiveMQ Broker and WebConsole installed.
This is running on a Windows 10 system and Java 1.8.

I'm trying to get the Web Console to work with ActiveMQ if I setup this model up using Apache DS it works fine but when I switch to Active Directory it will return an error "Exception occurred while processing this request, check the log for more information!"

Hawtio & system/console works fine in both AD and ADS models.
So I know that LDAP calls are working.

The servicemix log shows:

> ```
> 2017-02-22 11:26:22,334 | WARN  | qtp1056379895-88 | ServletHandler | 191 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.2.19.v20160908 |
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'brokerAdmin' on type org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade
> ....
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Insufficient roles/credentials for operation
> ```

I have been all over the internet and doc's trying to figure out what needs to be set to allow this to display.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I added role.mapping to the LDAP config.

This allowed me to map the AD Groups to Servicemix roles such as admin, user, webconsole etc.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.2/html/Security_Guide/ESBSecureContainer.html#JAASAuth-LDAPLoginModule